# I am not able to trace the error shown by browser

Tags: web-deployment, apache2.4

just before running my site on apache server, site ran properly on django server at port 8000
then i made necessary permssion changes and run the site on apache server 
apachectl configtest is ok

Configuration check via

```
grep -inRH "ServerName " /etc/apache2/ | grep "\s#"*
```

shows the result give below

```
/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/site.conf:2:  # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
/etc/apache2/apache2.conf:56:ServerName localhost
/etc/apache2/sites-available/site.conf:2:        # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf:2:        # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname an  port that
/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf:9:        #ServerName www.example.com
```

I tried adding ServerName localhost in site.conf file

but it doesn't seem to work

here is my site.conf code
                                                                                                                                                                        
        ServerName localhost

```
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html   

    Alias /static /home/user/site/static
    <Directory /home/user/site/static>
            Require all granted
    </Directory>

    Alias /media /home/usre/site/media
    <Directory /home/user/site/media>
            Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <Directory /home/user/site/site>
            <Files wsgi.py>
                    Require all granted
            </Files>
    </Directory>

    WSGIScriptAlias / /home/user/site/site/wsgi.py
    WSGIDaemonProcess django_app python-path=/home/user/site python-home=/home/user/site/venv
    WSGIProcessGroup django_app
```

I am not able to resolve that where the problem is.